# Splitting multiple functions from main program

Tags: c

Heres the code I found in the internet

```
/*program to add and subtract elements of two arrays.*/

#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 20 

/*  function    :   readArray() 
to read array elements. 
*/

 void    readArray(int a[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i< size;i++) 
    { 
        printf("Enter %d element :",i+1); 
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
    } 
} 

/*  function    : printArray() 
to print array elements. 
*/
void printArray(int a[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i < size; i++) 
        printf("%5d",a[i]); 
} 

/*  function    : addArray(), 
to add elements of two arrays. 
*/
void addArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i< size;i++) 
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i]; 
} 

/*  function    : subArray(), 
to subtract elements of two arrays. 
*/
void subArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i< size;i++) 
            c[i]=a[i]-b[i]; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int A[MAX],B[MAX],ADD[MAX],SUB[MAX]; 
    int i,n; 


    printf("\nEnter size of an Array :"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 

    printf("\nEnter elements of Array 1:\n"); 
    readArray(A,n); 
    printf("\nEnter elements of Array 2:\n"); 
    readArray(B,n); 

    /* add Arrays*/
    addArray(A,B,ADD,n); 
    /* subtract two Arrays*/
    subArray(A,B,SUB,n); 

    printf("\nArray elements after adding :\n"); 
    printArray(ADD,n); 

    printf("\nArray elements after subtracting :\n"); 
    printArray(SUB,n); 

    printf("\n\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I want to separate the functions from the main file.

```
void    readArray(int a[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i< size;i++) 
    { 
        printf("Enter %d element :",i+1); 
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
    } 
} 


void printArray(int a[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i < size; i++) 
        printf("%5d",a[i]); 
} 


void addArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i< size;i++) 
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i]; 
} 


void subArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i< size;i++) 
            c[i]=a[i]-b[i]; 
}
```

I know I need to make a header file but how do I do it? All I know on doing header files is when I use `#define` or constants.

btw I just copied the code from the internet to serve as an example since I have my practical final exams next week.

Thanks for all the answers. Gonna try how to do it with this

```
main.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"func.h"


int main()
{
int A[MAX],B[MAX],ADD[MAX],SUB[MAX];
int i,n;


printf("\nEnter size of an Array :");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\nEnter elements of Array 1:\n");
readArray(A,n);
printf("\nEnter elements of Array 2:\n");
readArray(B,n);


addArray(A,B,ADD,n);
subArray(A,B,SUB,n);


printf("\nArray elements after adding :\n");
printArray(ADD,n);

printf("\nArray elements after subtracting :\n");
printArray(SUB,n);

printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}


func.h
#pragma once
#define MAX 20
void readArray(int a[],int n);


void printArray(int a[],int n);



void addArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int n);



void subArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int n);






func.c
#include "func.h"
void    readArray(int a[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i< n;i++)
{
    printf("Enter %d element :",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

}
}


void printArray(int a[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i < n; i++)
    printf("%5d",a[i]);

}


void addArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i< n;i++)
    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];

}


void subArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i< n;i++)
        c[i]=a[i]-b[i];

}
```

i dont know if that is right or wrong

Edit: Solved... since it is a multiple use file you should always return;!

Comment: i've read that as well but i dont really understand how it works from their explanation...

Comment: First step is to create the header file. Next step is to create a .c file that contains the functions you are moving away from the main .c file. The header file provides the function prototypes to main's .c file when you import the header file. Finally, the .c file you create with the functions provides the actual functions when compiled.

Comment: ok.. so what do i put in my header file? is it like void readArray(int a[],int size);???

Comment: The answer below has good suggestions for what goes into the header file. It demonstrates the use of #defined guards to keep the compiler from reading the header file more than once for any given compilation unit. Probably not needed for a simple example, but in any reasonably large code base, it is needed.

Comment: ok i somehow get it... but how do i call my header file to be used by the main file?

Comment: @DaveNewman i've done my revise can you take a look at it... i dont know what to do since i keep getting lnk2019

Answer (score 1):

I add some information to MikeCAT's answer, which is totally correct, but since you are new to C, you might like some more explanation.

With his "include guard" Mike shows how to prevent an include file from being included multiple times. This can hapen for example when a .c file includes the .h file (`#include "myfile.h"`) and a .h file also includes it (an include file to collect all the includes, for example).

In this case it would do no harm, but in other cases it can do harm and multiple inclusion must be prevented. Only if the symbol is not (yet) defined, will the `#ifdef` bock be included in compilation.

To tell other compilation units (c-files) which types, functions and variables your module (`myfile.c`) makes available, you now specify them. The functions are a list of function names, their return types and their parameters, each terminated with a semicolon, as in Mike's example.

Variables are declared with the keyword `extern` before them, e.g.

```
extern int a_size;
```

This tells the compiler the variable exists, but not in this compilation unit. The linker will later resolve the variable or report it missing.

Types are declared just as is, with no special keywords, for example a game board:

```
typedef struct MY_BOARD {
    int n_pieces;
    int board[8][8];
} t_board;
```

Types are normally declared first so you can declare (extern) variables of it. Before the types are the constants, but you know about them already.

Mike ends with closing the conditionla compilation block of his multiple inclusion guard.

You have now written a good .h file.

Comment: thx for that... it cleared some of my questions... i've posted above my first try in doing header files. can you check if theres anything i missed apart from the one i dont know what to put here. sorry for the trouble

Comment: @micovillena You forgot to add semicolons after function prototype declarations.

Comment: yep... i even forgot to call the functions as well... can you take a look at it now?

Comment: @MikeCAT you can take a look at it now... but i keep _printArray and _readArray unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main what does that mean?

Comment: @micovillena Did you link required files correctly?

Comment: @MikeCAT i think i did. since i am getting no error for addArray and subArray... i just dont know what am i doing wrong

Comment: @micovillena It should be because you didn't use `addArray` and `subArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write prototypes of the functions you want to use in other files in header.

example:

```
/* "include guard": prevent problems which come from this file included multiple times */
#ifndef ARRAY_UTIL_H_GUARD_0F1BCF9D_9429_4D9B_A05A_07BE3D527F84
#define ARRAY_UTIL_H_GUARD_0F1BCF9D_9429_4D9B_A05A_07BE3D527F84

/* declarations of your functions */
void readArray(int a[],int size);
void printArray(int a[],int size);
void addArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size);
void subArray(int a[],int b[],int c[],int size);

/* end of "include guard" */
#endif
```

Comment: So that is my .h file and the separated functions will go to whatever.c?

Comment: Good practice is to keep the header file name and the .c file's name the same. Example let's give your header the name "array_util.h". Then your .c file should be named "array_util.c". The compiler doesn't actually require this, but anyone reading your code will greatly appreciate it. Your separated functions will go into that .c file.

Comment: I see... so i followed what you suggested i've posted it above. I'm sorry for being a trouble here